# Node.js windows service responds with reset

Tags: windows, node.js

I have been trying to get my Node.js app running on Windows as a service. I have done variations using winser(which uses nssm) and nssm directly and the result is the same. The service appears to be created correctly.

I can start the service.

netstat -an shows it listening on 0.0.0.0:2222

Attempts to connect result in a connection reset.

What should I be looking at to find the source of this reset?